# Adding two doubles in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a problem with summing two doubles

```
double a = 1e+020;
double b = -4000;
double res = a + b; //result = 1e+020
```

Why res is equal to a?

Comment: how do you display the result?

Comment: because the -4000 become insignificant for scientific notation.

Comment: Because floating point numbers store only limited number of leading digits

Comment: `1e+020` is a very large number, and `4000` is a very small number. Subtracting `4000` from `1e+020` will make almost no difference.

Comment: Consider that on most systems, you only have 64 bits to work with here and numbers that go as high as ~1e308 as well as including non-integers. A 64-bit integer type only goes up to ~10^19.

Comment: @chris the issue here is not magnitude but precision (refering to 1e308 is misleading)

Comment: @idclev463035818, My comment is about precision. There's a huge range to cover (which is what I was trying to demonstrate) and only 64 bits to do it.

Comment: @chris but range and precision are not directly related because seperate bits are used for the exponent

Comment: @idclev463035818, I think that's beside the point I was trying to make. It's confusing to a lot of people why not every integer is representable and I was trying to give some high-level intuition for _why_ so many numbers are unrepresentable. Not so much _which_ numbers, but the idea that you can pick whatever bit representation you want and it won't come anywhere close to having everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` has not infinite number of significant digits. You can query number of digits in base 10 with `std::numeric_limits`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(){
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10;
}
```

Typical output is

```
15
```

but you are requesting 16 significant digits.